# How to change the units of difftime after computing the values, and not using units="xxx" when performing the calculations

Tags: r, date

I am substracting dates. In the following example

```
bb

FECHA_EFECTO_ESTADO FECHA_ANIVERSARIO_POLIZA
9  2015-11-05 09:49:00               2015-11-05
10 2015-11-05 09:51:00               2015-11-04
```

the columns are posixct date values. To create a new variable which is the difference of the other variables I could use:

```
library (dplyr)
bb<-aa<-mutate(bb, day1=abs(FECHA_EFECTO_ESTADO-FECHA_ANIVERSARIO_POLIZA))
bb
  FECHA_EFECTO_ESTADO FECHA_ANIVERSARIO_POLIZA            day1
1 2015-11-05 09:49:00               2015-11-05  9.816667 hours
2 2015-11-05 09:51:00               2015-11-04 33.850000 hours
```

By default, the units (days, hours, seconds) if the day1 variable depends on the amount of the difference. If I want to have the difference in days, I could do:

```
bb<-mutate(bb, day2=abs (difftime(FECHA_EFECTO_ESTADO, FECHA_ANIVERSARIO_POLIZA, units="days" )))
bb
  FECHA_EFECTO_ESTADO FECHA_ANIVERSARIO_POLIZA            day1           day2
1 2015-11-05 09:49:00               2015-11-05  9.816667 hours 0.4090278 days
2 2015-11-05 09:51:00               2015-11-04 33.850000 hours 1.4104167 days
```

IS there a way to specify the units (days in this case) **after** doing the calculations? I might find further down the analysis that I would prefer to have the difference in hours for instance, so:
**How can I change the units of the day1 or day2 columns a posteriori?**
Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What is returned by `difftime` is an object of class "difftime".

Other function have methods for difftime. For example, to convert to the number of hours, as a numeric:

```
as.numeric(difftime("2015-12-07", "2015-12-05"), units="hours")
```

> `[1] 48`

Or, to get weeks:

```
as.numeric(difftime("2015-12-07", "2015-12-05"), units="weeks")
```

> `[1] 0.2857143`

Also, you might find it useful to remember that `POSIXct` objects are actually numbers! They represent the number of seconds elapsed since `‘1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC’`, (assumes Gregorian Calendar).

As a result, it can often be convenient to think of a unit of time of fixed duration (i.e., not something like "month", which isn't constant) and perform calculations using it. E.g., once your time difference is in seconds, it's to convert to other constant (technically there is a very fine scale variation in some of these, but most applications don't require attention to these details) time units like minutes, hours, days, or weeks.

Comment: thanks @rbatt . I was looking for a way to change the whole column `day2` to hours for instance; or column `day1`to days.  Taking from your answer I can see now that if I do `bb$day1<- as.numeric(bb$day1, units="days")`I can change the units of the variable day1 from hours to days!!

Comment: @MiguelRayonGonzalez If you found this answer useful, you should consider upvoting it. If it answered your question, you should consider accepting it.

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor `POSIXct` is not the same class as `difftime`. To get the seconds of a `POSIXct` object you need to wrap it in `format(...,format="%S")`.

Comment: what if you don't the know  the difference between two time stamps result is day, hour, week, month or year but you want the difference in hours. How would you do that?

Answer (score 11):

Now, thanks to @rbatt I have realised that, in my example, to change the units of variable day1, I can do `bb$day1<- as.numeric(bb$day1, units="days")`

And this will change the units to days:

```
FECHA_EFECTO_ESTADO FECHA_ANIVERSARIO_POLIZA            day1           day2
9  2015-11-05 09:49:00               2015-11-05  9.816667 hours 0.4090278 days
10 2015-11-05 09:51:00               2015-11-04 33.850000 hours 1.4104167 days

bb$day1<- as.numeric(bb$day1, units="days")

bb

   FECHA_EFECTO_ESTADO FECHA_ANIVERSARIO_POLIZA      day1           day2
9  2015-11-05 09:49:00               2015-11-05 0.4090278 0.4090278 days
10 2015-11-05 09:51:00               2015-11-04 1.4104167 1.4104167 days
```